Entity Search Using Gemini in Agents Builder - Retrieval Step Issues
I'm currently working on a project where I need to perform entity searches using Gemini in Agents Builder, specifically for company names. However, I'm struggling with the retrieval step and would appreciate any insights or suggestions you might have.
I'm particularly concerned about the ability of vector stores to effectively match company names or usernames when only an additional field like country (where the company is based) is available. I'm wondering if this limitation might be the root cause of my retrieval issues. Has anyone successfully implemented a similar setup where company names are matched accurately using vector stores with such limited context? If so, how did you overcome the challenges of disambiguating similar company names across different countries?
Here's a brief overview of my setup:

Data Preparation:


I export company names and country codes from my SQL database as JSON files.
Due to constraints, I change the file extension to .txt before uploading them to the data store.

An example of the data structure in these files is as follows:
{
"companyName": "Heaths Paint Center INC",
"countryCode": "USA"
},
{
"companyName": "Heath W Holtapp",
"countryCode": "USA"
}


Agent Instructions:


The agent is instructed to search for a company based on the provided name and country code.
It capitalizes each word in the company name and uses a tool to search for the most similar name in the records.
If a match is found, it returns the company name and the source in JSON format.

Despite this setup, the retrieval step often fails to return results for company names that are only slightly different from those in the data store. I am encountering inconsistent results. Sometimes, even when I use the exact same company names as those in the data store, the retrieval step fails to return any results. This inconsistency is perplexing, especially for such simple tests where I expect an exact match.
I have tried normalizing the company names by converting them to lowercase, removing punctuation, and standardizing common suffixes like "Inc." and "Ltd." before indexing them. Despite these efforts, the retrieval still fails frequently.
I was expecting the retrieval step to consistently return matches for exact or near-exact company names, especially given that the names are identical in some tests. This inconsistency suggests there might be an underlying issue with how the vector stores handle the matching, particularly when only an additional field like the country code is provided.
Here are some specific questions and issues I'd like to address:

Fuzzy Matching:


Is there a way to enable or improve fuzzy matching in the retrieval step to account for small variations in company names?
How can I ensure that similar names, even with slight differences, are matched correctly?


Vector Stores and Contextual Matching:


Does Gemini support vector stores for matching company names or usernames with additional fields like country codes?
If so, how can I optimize the vector store setup to improve retrieval accuracy?


Data Normalization and Preprocessing:


What are the best practices for normalizing and preprocessing company names before indexing them in the data store?
Are there any specific techniques or tools recommended for handling common variations in company names (e.g., "Inc.", "Ltd.")?


Handling Large Datasets:


Are there any performance considerations or limitations when working with large datasets in this context?
How can I ensure efficient and accurate retrieval from a large data store?

Any advice, examples, or resources you could provide would be greatly appreciated. I'm particularly interested in hearing from anyone who has successfully implemented a similar setup or faced and resolved similar issues.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Did you check out filter and boosting for data search? It requires that you have metadata in your data store which you can then use to filter only for specific metadata keys or boost metadata keys see https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/vertex/docs/concept/data-store-agent-performance#filter

Maybe I could filter by country code. Do you have any other use case ideas? So far, the Data Store tool automatically generated a filter like this in the Agents Builder interface but was not working properly. I got no results back.
